# How to use Cognito to Control API Access

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

We are building a number of microservices using API Gateway+lambda+DynamoDB. We need to secure these APIs using Cognito which we are using for user management. We will have a user pool and two groups with a different IAM role attached to each group. The need is users in one group should not be able to access all services and so the users in other group.
Any suggestions, how we can implement this?
The issue is ID token generated by Cognito is not validated by API gateway to check what level of access user has. All it checks is if Cognito ID token is valid or not.

Comment: I think you will have to do some additional validation in Lambda. Or, you can write a custom validator that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Gateway custom authorizers to validate policies attached to each group.

From AWS [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html):

> You can use groups in a user pool to control permission with Amazon API Gateway. The groups that a user is a member of are included in the ID token provided by a user pool when a user signs in. You can submit those ID tokens with requests to Amazon API Gateway, use a custom authorizer Lambda function to verify the token, and then inspect which groups a user belongs to.

Additional references to implement:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/